# Is it possible to have a non-template class subclass a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, subclass

I have a template class defined like so:

```
template <class T>
class Command {
public:
    virtual T HandleSuccess(std::string response) = 0;
    virtual std::string FullCommand() const = 0;
    // ... other methods here ...
};
```

Will C++ allow me to create a non-template subclass of a template class? What I mean is can I do something like this:

```
class NoopCommand : public Command<NoopResult> {
public:
    NoopResult HandleSuccess(std::string response);
    std::string FullCommand() const;
    // ... other methods here ...
};
```

As is that is not working for me because it says the following virtual functions are undefined:

```
T admix::Command<T>::HandleSuccess(std::string) [with T = admix::NoopResult]
std::string admix::Command<T>::FullCommand() const [with T = admix::NoopResult]
```

How can I specifically define them for the given T?

Comment: is this error issued by the compiler or the linker?

Comment: The error is from the compiler.

Comment: What compiler and version?  On the compiler I tried (gcc 4.2.1 for Darwin) that compiles cleanly for me.

Comment: Same compiler, gcc 4.2.1 on Darwin. Note that the error only occurs when actually trying to create an instance, because it considers the NoopCommand class to be abstract.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

litb found the solution on ##c++ last night.

The issue was I was passing a NoopCommand to a function like this:

```
void SendCommand(Command<T> command);
```

When I should have made the signature this:

```
void SendCommand(Command<T>& command);
```

Making that change allows everything to compile.

Answer (score 4):

As we figured out in IRC, that was because you have

1. Made your functions non-pure
2. Sliced the derived object part. So the base class functions were called because the object wasn't a complete derived object anymore.

(Below follows my suspicion on earlier versions of your question - i keep it for further consideration and to keep the comments meaningful)

---

<sub>I think the issue here is that the compiler is free to instantiate any virtual function member of a class template even if it's not used (i.e not called). Instantiating a function will need a function definition to be provided. Try to add this in the header, where the compiler will find them and instantiate a definition from:</sub>

```
template<typename T>
T Command<T>::HandleSuccess(std::string response) { /* put some default action ... */ }

template<typename T>
std::string Command<T>::FullCommand() const { /* put some default action ... */ }
```

C++ Standard `14.7.1/9`:

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a non-virtual
>   member function, a member class or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation. It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.

Comment: I gave default versions of both methods, but now I have a problem. The code is calling the default versions instead of the subclass' overridden versions, which means it doesn't consider my `NoopResult HandleSuccess(std::string response)` in the subclass to override the superclass.

Comment: As we figured out in IRC, that was because you have 1) Made your functions non-pure 2) sliced the derived object part. So the base class functions were called because the object wasn't a complete derived object anymore.

Comment: How is this relevant? Yes, per 14.7.1/9 the compiler is free to instantiate `Command<T>::HandleSuccess(std::string)`. But it's just a declaration that would be instantiated. Since it's a pure virtual declaration the subsequent lack of a definition is not an error.

Comment: The declaration is instantiated anyway (the declaration of any function is implicitly instantiated when its class is implicitly instantiated). But for a virtual function (and a pure one is also virtual), the function itself can be instantiated too. It's not immediately an error if the template definition is not available, because the definition could be exported. But if it isn't, then it's an error.

Comment: "Phases of translation", 2.1/1b8 says "Each translated translation unit is examined to produce a list of required instantiations. The definitions of the required templates are located. The program is ill-formed if any instantiation fails.". At least that's how i'm interpreting the matter.

Answer (score 3):

"virtual functions are undefined" means you have not defined the function bodies of NoopCommand::HandleSuccess and NoopCommand::FullCommand.

The following should solve your problem.

```
class NoopCommand : public Command<NoopResult> {
public:
    NoopResult HandleSuccess(std::string response) {}
    std::string FullCommand() const {}
    // ... other methods here ...
};
```

Or you you have a NoopCommand.cpp, make sure it's included in your build process.

Comment: I have defined them. I also defined superclass default versions instead of making them pure virtual. However, my default versions are being called instead of the overridden definitions in the subclass.

Comment: What is the definition of your 
NoopResult HandleSuccess(std::string response);
and
std::string FullCommand() const;

and how are you invoking them?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you use is widely known as the "[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)". so, yes, you can do that.
I can't think of a reason why it does not compile.

Comment: Actually that mistake was just when typing up the question, it has the argument in the code.

Comment: Does it matter that the the function definitions are in the .cpp file and not the .h?

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave compiles for me, without errors (after adding a `struct NoopResult { };`). Maybe there's a problem in the code you left out?

Comment: Did you include some code that tries to instantiate the class? The class is considered abstract by the compiler.

Comment: Yes. There may be link time issues if the bodies of `HandleSuccess` and `FullCommand` are missing of course - I assumed your error was from compile time, but since you accepted the other answer I guess they were from the linker?